# Same access token between different fetch_token requests

Tags: support, api, authentication, oauth2

**TL;DR:**

Is it (or *would it be*) possible to get the same `access_token` from one `fetch_token` request to another, provided that the user is the same?

**Scenario:**

1. An anonymous user authenticates with Stack Exchange on my website
2. He does some stuff which I save in my db (for instance he says he likes blue)
3. The day after, he visits my website again with another browser/computer
4. He tries to authenticate with his Stack Exchange account again
5. Obviously, I want to make sure that he logs on my site with the account he created in **1.**

**The problem:**

Currently, the `access_token` given in **4.** will be different than the one given in **1.** which has the following downsides:

- Each time someone logs in my website with his Stack Exchange account, I can't simply use the `access_token` to check if the user already exists in my db. I have to make one more request to get his `account_id` and check with that
- Which in turn, also forces me to store Stack Exchange's `account_id` in my db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each time you invoke `stackexchange.com/oauth/` you will get a fresh access token, even though old ones may still be valid.
For example:

1. Go to [`/me/inbox`<sup>Livedoc</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox) and hit <kbd>Get Token</kbd> twice, recording the token value each time (It will always be different).
2. Then go to [`/access-tokens/{accessTokens}`<sup>Livedoc</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens) and check each token. They will both still be valid! (Valid tokens return an entry in the `items` array. Invalid or expired tokens return nothing.)

At the very least, **one would expect that issuing a new token for the same app+permissions+user should invalidate old tokens for that app+permissions+user.**  Littering the bitbucket with lots of unused, but valid, tokens just makes it easier for bad guys. ;)

Returning the last-issued token, if it is still valid, would be convenient but there might be some reason not to.

You can submit a feature-request to improve these behaviors but, unless a definite vulnerability is shown, it may be a while before anything changes. (API development seems to have stalled.)

---

### Workaround-ish:

If you know who the user is by some other means (cookie, `localStorage`, etc.), and you stored her last valid `access_token`, you can use `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` to see if that token is still valid.
If it is, just use that token and skip the fresh call to `stackexchange.com/oauth/`.

**You need a way to track a user outside of `access_token`, but you should be doing that anyway.**
Tokens are meant to be ephemeral and [identification and authorization should be kept separate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512578.aspx).

Also, protect yourself and the user and `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}/invalidate` tokens when you are done with them or if you are calling `stackexchange.com/oauth/` for a fresh token.

Comment: "API development seems to have stalled" -> no, kiddin'? :)